# Django postgre migrate error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I changed my DB backends from sqlite3 to postgre. When I try to run migrate I have an error

```
MacBook-Pro-Oleg:avtofarm okorablev$ python3 manage.py migrate
```

Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, avtofarm, smart_selects, staticfiles, thumbnail
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, admin, callboard, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying callboard.0004_auto_20150701_1609...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "manufdate" cannot be cast automatically to type date
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 338, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 330, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 393, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 444, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
>   line 221, in handle
>       executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
>   line 110, in migrate
>       self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
>   line 148, in apply_migration
>       state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py",
>   line 115, in apply
>       operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py",
>   line 201, in database_forwards
>       schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
>   line 484, in alter_field
>       old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
>   line 636, in _alter_field
>       params,   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
>   line 111, in execute
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 79, in execute
>       return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 97, in **exit**
>       six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py",
>   line 658, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "manufdate" cannot be cast
>   automatically to type date HINT:  Specify a USING expression to
>   perform the conversion.

Model

```
class Zip(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category,null=True,verbose_name='Категория')
subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(SubCategory,chained_field="category",
    chained_model_field="category",
    show_all=False,
    auto_choose=True,verbose_name='Подкатегория')
type = models.ForeignKey(Type,verbose_name='Состояние')
zipgroup = models.ForeignKey(ZipGroup,null=True,verbose_name='Группа запчастей')
ziptype = models.ForeignKey(ZipType,null=True,verbose_name='Вид запчасти')
cartype = models.ForeignKey(CarType,null=True,verbose_name='Тип авто')
carmodel = models.ForeignKey(CarModel,null=True,verbose_name='Модель транспорта')
carbodytype = models.ForeignKey(CarBodyType,null=True,verbose_name='Тип кузова')
catalognumber = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name='Номер по каталогу')
manufdate = models.CharField(max_length=4,null=True,verbose_name='Год выпуска')
title = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Заголовок объявления')
description = models.TextField(null=True,verbose_name='Описание')
price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена')
user = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name='Пользователь')
creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
is_sell = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: How is the `manufdate` column in your postgresql table defined? Sounds like you have a `date` column and you need `char(4)`.

Comment: CREATE TABLE callboard_zip
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  type text NOT NULL,
  catalognumber text,
  manufdate text,
  title text NOT NULL,
  description text NOT NULL,
  price integer NOT NULL,
  carbodytype_id integer NOT NULL,
  carmodel_id integer NOT NULL,
  cartype_id integer NOT NULL,
  category_id integer NOT NULL,
  subcategory_id integer NOT NULL,
  zipgroup_id integer NOT NULL,
  ziptype_id integer NOT NULL,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was solved after I deleted database, made new database and one more time did makemigrations and migrate. But I think should be another way how you can decide this problem better without deleting database

Comment: This is not a solution that should be accepted. One can almost never delete a db

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into your migrations code (for application which contains `Zip` model). Looks like there is some issue with migrations, because you receive the error about date conversion, when in current model you have `CharField` type for `manufdate` column.

Comment: Migrations are in ```migrations``` directories inside of each application directory.